# Fastest and efficient way of parsing raw data from file

Tags: c++, performance, multiplatform

I'm working on some project and I'm wondering which way is the most efficient to read a huge amount of data off a file(I'm speaking of file of 100 lines up to 3 billions lines approx., can be more thought). Once read, data will be stored in a structured data set (`vector<entry>` where "entry" defines a structured line).

A structured line of this file may look like : 
  `string int int int string string`
which also ends with the appropriate platform `EOL` and is TAB delimited

What I wish to accomplish is :

1. Read file into memory (`string`) or `vector<char>`
2. Read raw data from my buffer and format it into my data set.

I need to consider memory footprint and have a fast parsing rate.
I'm already avoiding usage of `stringstream` as they seems too slow.

I'm also avoiding multiple I/O call to my file by using :

```
// open the stream
std::ifstream is(filename);

// determine the file length
is.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
std::size_t size = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

// "out" can be a std::string or vector<char>
out.reserve(size / sizeof (char));
out.resize(size / sizeof (char), 0);

// load the data
is.read((char *) &out[0], size);

// close the file
is.close();
```

I've thought of taking this huge `std::string` and then looping line by line, I would extract line information (string and integer parts) into my data set row. Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT : This application may run on a 32bit, 64bit computer, or on a super computer for bigger files.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not an expert on this field, but what you need to be very careful with is your vector!  If you're storing entries instead of pointers (smart) you will end up having all your objects copied every time your vector resize. If your raw file provides you with a header with the # of items, make sure to `reserve` your vector for these elements

Comment: With such a simple format the parsing speed is pretty irrelevant. Whatever you do, it will still be a thousand times (!) faster than the actual reading of the file from disc. Reading the file into memory in one go is also not a particularly good solution due to memory consumption. However, chunking the input into blocks can help. If you really need high performance then there’s no way around memory-mapped files.

Comment: All common I/O libraries (like C++ streams and C stdio) do buffering for you.  Most operating systems will figure out you are reading a big file sequentially and read ahead for you.  All tuning should be data driven.  So write a clean piece of code and then profile it to see where the time is going.

Comment: Raymond Chen has a mini-series dealing with optimizing a similar scenario parts [0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/09/415714.aspx) [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/10/415991.aspx) [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/11/416430.aspx) [3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/13/417183.aspx) [4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/16/417865.aspx) (also has a parts 5 & 6). It is slightly different, but the considerations should be the same.

Comment: Assuming your 3 strings are 1 byte long and each int is 4 bytes, each entry needs at least 18 bytes.  With 3 billion lines of data you are talking about 54 GB of memory.  This will not fit in a 32-bit process.  With a 64-bit process, most desk tops (with 8 GB RAM) will start thrashing and get super slow.

Comment: you should add a tag what OS you are targeting. e.g. Windows has memory mapped files.

Comment: better use `deque` to avoid copying when re-sizing.

Answer (score 0):

Some random thoughts:

- Use vector::resize() at the beginning (you did that)
- Read large blocks of file data at a time, at least 4k, better still 256k.  Read them into a memory buffer, parse that buffer into your vector.
- Don't read the whole file at once, this might needlessly lead to swapping.
- sizeof(char) is always 1 :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought of reading chunk of data, and afterwards that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

while i cannot speak for supercomputers with 3 gig lines you will go nowhere in memory on a desktop machine.

i think you should first try to figure out all operations on that data. you should try to design all algorithms to operate sequentially. if you need random access you will do swapping all the time. this algorithm design will have a big impact on your data model.

so do not start with reading all data, just because that is an easy part, but design the whole system with a clear view an what data is in memory during the whole processing.

---

update
when you do all processing in a **single run** on the stream and separate the data processing in stages (read - preprocess - ... - write) you can utilize multithreading effectivly.

---

finally

- whatever you want to do in a loop over the data, try to keep the number of loops a minimum. averaging for sure you can do in the read loop.
- immediately make up a test file the size you expect to be the worst case in size and time two different approaches

.

```
time
loop
    read line from disk
time
loop
    process line (counting words per line)
time
loop
    write data (word count) from line to disk
time
```

versus.

```
time
loop
    read line from disk
    process line (counting words per line)
    write data (word count) from line to disk
time
```

if you have the algorithms already use yours. otherwise make up one (like counting words per line). if the write stage does not apply to your problem skip it. this test does take you less than an hour to write but can save you a lot.

Comment: Yes, all algorithms are design to be sequential so I should be fine with memory swapping, and I'll read chunk of data instead of the entire file.

Comment: your question and code snippet suggest that you want to read the whole file at once. what you do is to read a multi-gig-file into memory that has to be swapped onto the disk. then you close the file. technically you have done nothing. you have some few gig in memory (from the tail of the file) and the rest of the data (especially the begin) resides on disk. if your algorithm starts to process your data the data must be swapped in. you wait for the disk.

Comment: in contrary, if you read one line, preprocess it, process it, post process it, do magic with it, store the results to disk and continue with reading the next line you have little memory footprint and the overall processingtime is either one full read or one full write or one full processing whatever is bigger. try not to act as hot-water container, act as continuous-flow heater. of couse you shall not read single chars from stream but getline() should be ok (as it already provides some parsing you have to do anyway)

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider all this, but I still have to load complete data in memory as I need to computes a profile based on means and standard deviations